# display odd and even rows into 2 separate columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, split, case

But given requirements is:

`a~b~c~d~e~f`

and O/p like:

```
 a b
 c d 
 e f
```

Here a, e is odd value and c is even value. So i tried to use this query using `string_split()` to separate this symbol '~'. Can anyone please help?

In this query I'm not getting odd even separate column output:

```
select 
   C.CID, c.nunique, 
   Row Number() OVER (ORDER BY C.CID) as RowNum,
   CASE 
      WHEN (ROW Number () OVER(ORDER BY c.CID)) % 2 = 0 THEN s.value 
      WHEN (Row Number() OVER (ORDER BY c.CID)) % 2 = 1 THEN s.value
      ELSE " invalid"
   END
from Candidate c
cross apply STRING SPLIT(applist,~) s
```

Comment: I am not able to understand what you want. Can you paste an example with input data and result, please?

Comment: Unfortunately `STRING_SPLIT` can return sub strings in any order. The best bet is recursive cte.

Answer (score 1):

**Answer:**

You need to split the stored sequence using a spliiter to get the substrings and the order of the substrings. A JSON-based approach may help here - simply transform the text into a valid JSON array (`a~b~c~d~e~f` into `["a","b","c","d","e","f"]'`) and parse the array with `OPENJSON()`. The result from the `OPENJSON()` call is a table with columns `key`, `value` and `type` and in case of a JSON array, the `key` column contains the 0-based index of each item in the array:

```
SELECT c.cid, j.odd, j.even
FROM (VALUES (1, 'a~b~c~d~e~f')) c (cid, applist)
CROSS APPLY (
   SELECT 
      MIN(CASE WHEN CONVERT(int, [key]) % 2 = 0 THEN [value] END) AS [odd],
      MIN(CASE WHEN CONVERT(int, [key]) % 2 = 1 THEN [value] END) AS [even]
   FROM OPENJSON(CONCAT('["', REPLACE(c.applist, '~', '","'), '"]'))
   GROUP BY CONVERT(int, [key]) / 2
) j
```

Result:

```
cid odd even
1   a   b
1   c   d
1   e   f
```

**Update:**

If JSON-based approach is not an option, a recursive CTE may help:

```
CREATE TABLE Candidate (cid int, applist varchar(max))
INSERT INTO Candidate (cid, applist) 
VALUES (1, 'a~b~c~d~e~f'), (2, 'g~h~i~i')

;WITH rCTE AS (
   SELECT 
      c.cid,
      LEFT(CONCAT(c.applist, '~'), CHARINDEX('~', CONCAT(c.applist, '~')) - 1) AS substring,
      STUFF(CONCAT(c.applist, '~'), 1, CHARINDEX('~', CONCAT(c.applist, '~')), '') AS remaining,
      0 AS position
   FROM Candidate c 
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 
      r.cid,
      LEFT(r.remaining, CHARINDEX('~', r.remaining) - 1),
      STUFF(r.remaining, 1, CHARINDEX('~', r.remaining), ''),
      r.position + 1
   FROM rCTE r
   WHERE LEN(r.remaining) > 0
)
SELECT
   cid, 
   MIN(CASE WHEN position % 2 = 0 THEN [substring] END) AS [odd],
   MIN(CASE WHEN position % 2 = 1 THEN [substring] END) AS [even]
FROM rCTE
GROUP BY cid, position / 2
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

**Using `STRING_SPLIT()`:**

Note, that although `STRING_SPLIT()` is an option, use this function carefully, because as is mentioned in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#remarks), *the output rows might be in any order* and *the order is not guaranteed to match the order of the substrings in the input string*.

```
SELECT 
   c.cid, 
   MIN(CASE WHEN rn % 2 = 0 THEN [value] END) AS [odd],
   MIN(CASE WHEN rn % 2 = 1 THEN [value] END) AS [even]
FROM (VALUES 
   (1, 'a~b~c~d~e~f'),
   (2, 'g~h~i~i')
) c (cid, applist)
CROSS APPLY (
   SELECT [value], ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) - 1 rn
   FROM STRING_SPLIT(c.applist, '~')
) s
GROUP BY c.cid, s.rn / 2
```

Comment: Thankyou for the answer! its really helpful and the output you have showed is perfect.. but my requirement is to solve without using OpenJson()

Comment: Thanks a lot for explaining these 3 different methods to solve my question... CTE method helped me to score more marks.